# SSIS Download the files using FTP Task inside the For Each loop by passing the Variable Enumerator

Tags: ssis, ssis-2017

Download the files using FTP Task inside the For Each loop by passing the Variable Enumerator to set the Remote Path Variable

1. I am loading the list of  files to download in a variable.( Verified and I can see the list of files)
2. Using the ForEach loop container I am receiving the file names using the Variable Enumator and passing it to the FTP Task inside the ForEach loop. (Verified and I can see the filenames one by one)
3. In the FTP Task when I try to set the remote path variable as the file name from the for each loop it is showing the error 
   FTP task variable does not begin with '/' error
4. When I manually set the Remote Path with the "/" + User::fileName during the run time I am getting an error message "Path is not of a legal form"

Comment: Have you tried without the variable and loop (i.e. simply hard code the values for one of the files and see if it functions)?

Comment: Yes, it is working with the hard coded ftp file path. Thanks

Comment: You need to set an expression that drives the path based on the variable @lyyapan

Answer (score 0):

In the SSIS FTP task set the delay validation to true in the properties. which will validate the Remote Path during the run time and it will resolve setting the remote path value from variable.